# Ruby on Rails: finding a model instance from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, model-associations, belongs-to

Currently I have a has_many and belongs_to association between a Project model and a Invitation model. I have a form_form invitation in the show action of the projects controller.

projects/show.html.erb

```
<div class="center">
    <h1><%= @project.title %></h1>

    <%= form_for @invitation do |f| %>
        <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name %><br>
        <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Choosing a target user and submitting the form will take the current user to the 'new' invitation page, and the user_id will have been saved for the new invitation. However, I also need a project_id to be saved, and I cannot figure out how I could do this. I was trying to see if I can define an instance variable @project in the 'create' action of the invitations_controller but I can't find out how.

invitations_controller.rb

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
end

def create
    @invitation = @project.create_invitation(invitation_params)
    if @invitation.save
        flash[:success] = "Invitation sent!"
        redirect_to @invitation
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def invitation_params
        params.require(:invitation).permit(:user_id, :project_id, :description)
    end
end
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is add the id as a hidden field. Your strong params should take care of project_id it looks like:

```
<%= form_for @invitation do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, @project.id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller, just use the params to make a new one. Passing the id through the new method will associate the record for you.

```
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new invitation_params
  if @invitation.save
    flash[:success] = "Invitation sent!"
    redirect_to @invitation
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Also note, when you call `create_invitation` that actually calls the create method right there. So it's already saved. The corresponding to `new` where it's just built in memory is `build_invitation(invitation_params)`

Comment: Thanks! This works, except it should be "<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id %>".

Answer (score 3):

Build your `invitations` in association with `project`

```
# view
...
<%= form_for @project.invitations.build do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

# controller
def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(invitation_params)
  if @invitation.save
    flash[:success] = "Invitation sent!"
    redirect_to @invitation
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Should this save the project's id to the project_id column of the new invitation instance?

Comment: I still get "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvitationsController#create", "Couldn't find Project without an ID
" in this line "<%= Project.find(@invitation.project_id) %>".

Comment: in `invitations_controller.rb` on which line you are facing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvitationsController#create`?
 The code you shown is of view... which view is this?

Comment: If I click "Send Invitation," it leads me to the invitations/new.html.erb because I have not yet filled out a description (which I validated the presence of). Just to check that the project_id has been saved, I tried the line "<%= Project.find(@invitation.project_id) %>" in invitations/new.html.erb.

Comment: I can see that after you click `send invitation`, you  go to `InvitationsController#create` which is leading you to `InvitationsController#show`, `redirect_to @invitation`. I think m not getting you

Comment: I think I got it to go to show now, but the project_id is still not saved. I get "undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass" in "<h1>Invitation from <%= link_to @invitation.project, @invitation.project.title %></h1>" in invitations/show.html.erb.

Comment: If I look at the console, I see that the project_id is not saved.

Comment: #<Invitation id: 5, description: "Join us!", user_id: 4, project_id: nil, created_at: "2014-08-02 21:26:38", updated_at: "2014-08-02 21:26:38">

Comment: can you post ur params coming to `InvitationsController#create` from new invitation form?

Comment: I just get "{"id"=>"5"}" but this is the show action of invitations. I'm not sure how I can view the params for 'create'.

Comment: you can check it on console log of your `rails server` terminal

Comment: Processing by InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ex4vWzaPlLXYSFYMD2LnVnSDIN+grdaF1Jcj9avUdWE=", "invitation"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "description"=>"Join us!"}, "commit"=>"Send Invitation"}

Comment: I know that project_id isn't showing up here but I thought "@project.invitations.build" automatically saves the project_id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58554/discussion-between-raj-and-user3104471).

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to include the parent `Project` model in the `Invitation` form, you can put them in an array like this:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @invitation] do |f| %>
    ....
<% end %>
```